# Functional test in Laravel with External URL ( Google Login)

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm trying to test the Google Login in my Laravel App.

When I try to reach Google Login page I get a 404.

My idea is that in TestCase.php, I have a variable:

```
    protected $baseUrl = 'http://laravel.dev';
```

So, it could make a conflict.... well the thing is I don't know how to do it, or to fix it!

Here is my code:

```
$this->visit('/auth/login')
     ->click('google'); 
    dump(Request::url()); // https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
    $this->dump(); --> Gives me a 404 page
```

Any idea is welcome !

Comment: I have a similar issue where I'm using an external auth provider and do a redirect to get a session token.  I really want to test the login functionality but the redirect is giving me a 404 and I don't know why.

Comment: So we are in the same boat ;)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is NO. The framework doesn't support it. If you dig a little bit you will found when you test with "visit", the request was not actually send out. In the call method of class MakesHttpRequests, it initialize a laravel http kernel and put the request thru it. No http request was actually issued.

```
    $kernel = $this->app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel');

    $this->currentUri = $this->prepareUrlForRequest($uri);

    $this->resetPageContext();

    $request = Request::create(
        $this->currentUri, $method, $parameters,
        $cookies, $files, array_replace($this->serverVariables, $server), $content
    );

    $response = $kernel->handle($request);
```

The only way you can try is to mock this part.

Comment: Can you explain a bit how to implement the mock part?